# Xamarin Forms Maps change pin marker to image

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin.forms

I've done everyhing shown in the following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map-pin

Works great shows the image named pin.png

I want to keep that one but add another pin with a DIFFERENT image.

What should I add/change in my code to do that?

This is what I currectly use to set the pin

```
CustomPin pin4 = new CustomPin
            {
                Type = PinType.Place,
                Position = new Position(9.936165, -84.039919),
                Label = "Fin",
            };
            map.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin> { pin };
            map.Pins.Add(pin4);
```

How can I use the markeroptions seticon?

Comment: What have you done so far to implement the other image? What issues did you face?

Comment: I tried creating another renderer class but faced a lot of error, plus in the android renderer I don't see where is call to pin.png, in the iOS one there's this line "annotationView.Image = UIImage.FromFile("pin.png");"

Answer (score 0):

Follow the docs you provided, you could use the `MarkerOptions.SetIcon` to represent a customized  marker.

The implementation of Android custom renderer:

```
    public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer, GoogleMap.IInfoWindowAdapter
{
    List<CustomPin> customPins;

    public CustomMapRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            NativeMap.InfoWindowClick -= OnInfoWindowClick;
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
            customPins = formsMap.CustomPins;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMapReady(GoogleMap map)
    {
        base.OnMapReady(map);

        NativeMap.InfoWindowClick += OnInfoWindowClick;
        NativeMap.SetInfoWindowAdapter(this);
    }

    protected override MarkerOptions CreateMarker(Pin pin)
    {
        var marker = new MarkerOptions();
        marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Position.Longitude));
        marker.SetTitle(pin.Label);
        marker.SetSnippet(pin.Address);
        marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.cactus));
        return marker;
    }

    void OnInfoWindowClick(object sender, GoogleMap.InfoWindowClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var customPin = GetCustomPin(e.Marker);
        if (customPin == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customPin.Url))
        {
            var url = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(customPin.Url);
            var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, url);
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    public Android.Views.View GetInfoContents(Marker marker)
    {
        var inflater = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService) as Android.Views.LayoutInflater;
        if (inflater != null)
        {
            Android.Views.View view;

            var customPin = GetCustomPin(marker);
            if (customPin == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
            }

            if (customPin.Name.Equals("Xamarin"))
            {
                view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.XamarinMapInfoWindow, null);
            }
            else
            {
                view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MapInfoWindow, null);
            }

            var infoTitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowTitle);
            var infoSubtitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowSubtitle);

            if (infoTitle != null)
            {
                infoTitle.Text = marker.Title;
            }
            if (infoSubtitle != null)
            {
                infoSubtitle.Text = marker.Snippet;
            }

            return view;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Android.Views.View GetInfoWindow(Marker marker)
    {
        return null;
    }

    CustomPin GetCustomPin(Marker annotation)
    {
        var position = new Position(annotation.Position.Latitude, annotation.Position.Longitude);
        foreach (var pin in customPins)
        {
            if (pin.Position == position)
            {
                return pin;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

The layout of MapInfoWindow, XamarinMapInfoWindow, you could check the link below.
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/CustomRenderers/Map/Droid/Resources/layout

For more details about ios, uwp, you could download the source file from GitHub for reference.
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/CustomRenderers/Map

Comment: But how can I use the SetIcon?

Comment: I have updated my reply. Please check it.